# ¿Cómo actualizar una listView desde otra pagina?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hola muy buenos días a todos,

Contexto: Tengo una TabbedPage, y ahí dentro de ella están añadidas 3 páginas, en el NavigationPage de la TabbedPage, tengo un Picker (Combobox), que al elegir un item dentro de él, tiene un evento asignado de itemselect.
Página dentro de TabbePage (Se llama Escaneo), dentro de Escaneo tengo una ListView, que debería cargar con los folios según lo seleccionado en el Picker ya mencionado.

La pregunta es: apartir de todo ello, quiero que en el evento que tiene el Picker, al seleccionar un item el listView de la página de Escaneo se recargue con las coincidencias encontradas.

Mi problema radica en que no puedo acceder al ListView desde otra página y recargarlo, no sé como hacerlo, intenté con un Timer pero no me sirvió, se cicla la aplicación.

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: si no muestras código es casi imposible que podamos adivinar cómo elaboraste tu proyecto.